# Function to strip specific characters and HTML code

Tags: mysql, sql, function, loops, delimiter

I have a function that I found and modified to strip certain characters and HTML tags, that I am using in a MySQL view.

I am able to create the function using MySQL workbench, but for some reason, it will not create from the command line 'mysql' from a shell prompt. It gives an error about the delimiter. When we take out the delimiter, it doesn't appear to like the LOOP or SET lines either.

Any suggestions on why this works in the one place but not the other? Also, is there a better way of writing this function?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `strip_tags`;
DELIMITER // 
CREATE FUNCTION `strip_tags`( $str TEXT ) RETURNS text
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
  SET $str = COALESCE( $str, '' );
  LOOP 
    SET $str = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE($str,'&reg;',''),'®',''),'&trade;',''),'™',''),'&egrave;','è'),'&amp;','&');
    SET $start = locate( "<", $str, $start ); 
    IF ( !$start ) THEN 
      RETURN $str;
    END IF;
    SET $end = locate( ">", $str, $start );
    IF ( !$end ) THEN 
      SET $end = $start;
    END IF;
    SET $str = 
            INSERT 
                   ( 
                $str, 
                $start, 
                $end - $start + 1, 
                "" 
                   );
  END LOOP;
END
// DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: remove the `$` from the variables and test again.

Comment: In all places, including the function definition?

Comment: Yes. It is not needed in MySql, I'm suspecting the `$` character may be causing the problem this or the `&` one of the two is causing your problem in the console.

Comment: How would I replace the &? That is the HTML character I need to replace. Would I escape it like \& ?

Comment: I just realized your problem. Your `insert` command at the end before the `end loop` is wrong. You can't set an insert command into a variable. Also even if you want to run that insert command it is wrong as the syntax for an insert is `insert INTO SOMETABLE (columns,list,here) values (values, list, here, and, dontUSEdoubleQUOTESforSTRINGvalues);`